# Google shows URLs for other countries when searching for my site by country

Tags: seo, multilingual

I have a site that's available for different countries and the URL looks like: `www.example.com/country`

The problem appears when I look for my site and I want to look for a specific country. For example I want to search for France, so I Google "my site France". The first result is `example.com/france`, that's fine but then the second or third result is `example.com/other_country` and that's not correct and on the first result if it shows sections of my site, it shows for example the contact section as `example.com/germany/contactus`

The problem is that looking for a specific country it shows content designed for other countries.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rel="alternate" hreflang="x"` to tell Google which pages are for which locales.

In the head of every page which is duplicated for multiple locales, list the alternate pages with the relevant hreflang set:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://example.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://example.com/germany" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is doing the right thing. It's actually doing what is in its program. I would better say change your website architecture by using geoIP:

Check that you have the [mod_geoip](http://www.maxmind.com/app/mod_geoip) module (GeoIP Extension) installed on your server.

Then, tweak your .htaccess file accordingly :

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

# Start Redirecting countries

# Canada
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^CA$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ca.abcd.com$1 [L]

# India
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^IN$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://in.abcd.com$1 [L]

# etc etc etc...
```

Comment: The Googlebot primarily crawls from U.S. IP addresses, so that might result in the OP's content for other countries to no longer get indexed.